# Mod-Rewrite Dynamic URLs

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've searched and searched and tried and tried for 2 days solid now on how to make myself some friendly URL's on a CMS I am making to teach my self php.

I am trying to change:

www.mydomain.com/cms/index.php?id=30

To:

www.mydomain.com/cms/30

to begin with, I already have created another function to change it from id to a seourl but I can't even get the basic number version working yet.

I have tried hundred of combinations of how to write my .htaccess file this is my current one which seemingly does nothing:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule cms/index/id/(.*) cms/index.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule cms/index/id/(.*)/ cms/index.php?id=$1
```

How my urls are dynamical created:

```
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel, seourl FROM pages WHERE showing='1' ORDER BY pageorder ASC";
        $query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error());
    $menuDisplay = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $pid = $row["id"];
            $linklabel = $row["linklabel"];
            $seourl = $row["seourl"];
    $menuDisplay .= '<a href="index.php?id=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '<a><br .>';
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Does anyone have any idea or solutions on what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Will the way my link is generated be effecting how to do the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
RewriteRule cms/([/d]+) cms/index.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Using the above my url's do not change and when navigating to www.mydomain.com/cms/30 it returns Not Found

The requested URL /cms/30 was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you sure your webserver is reading .htaccess and is able to do the rewrites?

Comment: How can I test that it is able to do the rewrite? My server host said that mod_rewrite is allowed and working on there end.

Comment: Create simple a.html and b.html and try
RewriteRule a.html b.html

Comment: Navigating to a.html takes me to the b.html content so its working that way. I've edited original post with how my urls are generated.

Comment: Ok, now try   
RewriteRule ^([/d]+).html$ a.html?Id=$1  

And check whether yourdomain.com/1.html or 2.html will point to   a.html?Id=Number